# javascript data manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have objects in array as

```
var arr = [{'name':'one','age':24},{'name':'two','age':21}]
```

I have assigned this array to another variable `var newVar = arr`. Now I am changing value of an objects of `newVar` as `newVar[0].age = 18`, But change the value of object of `newVar` get reflected in `arr(original data)` as well. After change value in `newVar`, `arr` is

```
var arr = [{'name':'one','age':18},{'name':'two','age':21}]
```

I want original data should be independent of changing values of another variable holding same data. How can I get it with java script?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript handles objects by reference. If you have to change value in just a object you should "clone" it. This way there will be two different objects.

How to clone a object:

[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

use new Array().

```
var arr = [{'name':'one','age':24},{'name':'two','age':21}];
var newArr=new Array(arr);
```

Comment: this idea is not working

Comment: see working example [http://jsfiddle.net/2CmWC/](http://jsfiddle.net/2CmWC/)

Comment: Check the result in console http://jsfiddle.net/rZhm5/

Answer (score 0):

To copy an array you would use `slice`. Unfortunately slice makes only a shallow copy. To make a deep clone you can use `map` method + `$.extend` to clone object:

```
var arr = [{'name':'one','age':24},{'name':'two','age':21}]
var newArr = arr.map(function(el) {
    return $.extend({}, el);
});

newArr[0].name = 'TEST'
console.log(newArr[0].name, arr[0].name); // TEST one
```

Or it can be event shorter using some javascript magic:

```
var newArr = arr.map($.extend.bind(null, {}));
```

Result is the same.

Comment: I don't want to use `jQuery`.

Comment: So just use any other extend/mixin implementation, for example from [this](http://andrewdupont.net/2009/08/28/deep-extending-objects-in-javascript/) post.